# useing realloc() many times

Tags: c, memory, dynamic, allocation, realloc

which one of the following is preferable

```
file=fopen(argv[1],"r");
arr=(unsigned int *)malloc(4);

while(!feof(file))
{
  ++arr_size;
  arr=(unsigned int *)realloc(arr,arr_size*sizeof(unsigned int)
  fscanf(file,"%u\n",&arr[arr_size-1]);
}
fclose(file);
```

or this

```
arr=(unsigned int *)malloc(some_size*sizeof(unsigned int));
file=fopen(argv[1],"r");
arr=(unsigned int *)malloc(4);

while(!feof(file))
{
  ++arr_size;
  fscanf(file,"%u\n",&arr[arr_size-1]);
}
fclose(file);
```

Comment: The 2nd one has a memory leak? You reassign malloced space without freeing it and don't even use the first line?

Comment: With `realloc` you also have to be careful, if there's an error and it returns null, you lost your original pointer the way you've written it.

Comment: The second one also has a massive buffer overrun, assuming that the input file is more than 4 bytes long.

Comment: `arr=(unsigned int *)malloc(4);` from the second example should be dropped.

Comment: In C, better not cast the return from `malloc` or `realloc`:  http://c-faq.com/malloc/mallocnocast.html

Answer (score 1):

Why not the third way - work out when you open the file how much memory you require?

Comment: how to do that. the text files dose not contain file hearers. hence i should read the file top to bottom. and once again to read the ints. so i should read the file twice?

Comment: @R Krishna Sagar: you can get the file size with `fstat` on Posix, `GetFileSizeEx` on Windows, or more portably you can `fseek` to the end of the file and then `ftell` to find your current offset, which is the file size. Be sure to check the integer types used for sizes in the API you use, if there's any chance you'll encounter large files (>2GB), since the portable one (`ftell`) only uses `long`.

Comment: `ftell` is the preferred method; `fstat` can fail to give an answer for certain special files and devices. Actually `ftello` is better when you have POSIX functions available, but if the file is bigger than `long` it's almost sure not to fit in memory anyway...